# Converting Int to Color in C# for Silverlight's WriteableBitmap

Tags: c#, silverlight

In Silverlight 3 there is now a WriteableBitmap which provides get/put pixel abilities. This can be done like so:

```
// setting a pixel example
WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(400, 200);
Color c = Colors.Purple;
bitmap.Pixels[0] = c.A << 24 | c.R << 16 | c.G << 8 | c.B;
```

Basically, setting a Pixel involves setting its color, and that comes by bitshifting the alpha, red, blue, green values into an integer.

My question is, how would you turn an integer back to a Color? What goes in the missing spot in this example:

```
// getting a pixel example
int colorAsInt = bitmap.Pixels[0];
Color c;
// TODO:: fill in the color c from the integer ??
```

Thanks for any help you might have, I'm just not up on my bit shifting and I'm sure others will run into this roadblock at some point.

Answer (score 7):

using the reflector i found how R,G,B are parsed in the standard .net call (not available in Silverlight):

```
System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromWin32()
```

from that i guessed how to get the alpha channel as well, and this does the job:

```
Color c2 = Color.FromArgb((byte)((colorAsInt >> 0x18) & 0xff), 
                          (byte)((colorAsInt >> 0x10) & 0xff), 
                          (byte)((colorAsInt >> 8) & 0xff), 
                          (byte)(colorAsInt & 0xff));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could possibly use [BitConverter.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4(VS.95).aspx)() to convert your int to a byte array that would work with the overloads of FromArgb that silverlight has...

```
Color.FromArgb(BitConverter.GetBytes(intVal)); 

// or if that doesn't work
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intVal);
Color.FromArgb(bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);
```

Comment: the second suggestion here works great, but the bits are backwards, this works:
Color.FromArgb(bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);

Comment: This would be horrendously (unacceptably) slow for operating on the pixels of a bitmap.

Comment: oops - updated the example accordingly.  thanks for catching that :)

Answer (score 2):

What has not been covered is that `WriteableBitmap` uses ***premultiplied*** ARGB32 so if you have a semitransparent pixel the R, G, and B values are scaled from 0 to the Alpha value.

To get the Color value back, you need to do the opposite and scale it back up to 0 to 255. Something as shown below.

```
r = (byte)(r * (255d / alpha))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the [ColorTranslator class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.aspx), but I'm not sure it's available in SilverLight or what you need. It's absolutely a good one to be aware of though.

Edit: [Here was one person's suggestion](http://silverlight.net/forums/t/6026.aspx) (use reflection to duplicate the class, so from then on you have a converter available that people are already familiar with).

Comment: good suggestion on using the reflector.. it got me to where i could read the R,G,B values, and after a bit more hacking I got the alpha parsing as well.. i added an answer with it using only bit shifting..

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Color ToColor(this uint argb)
{
    return Color.FromArgb((byte)((argb & -16777216) >> 0x18),
                          (byte)((argb & 0xff0000) >> 0x10),
                          (byte)((argb & 0xff00) >> 8),
                          (byte)(argb & 0xff));
}
```

and using:

```
Color c = colorAsInt.ToColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work:

```
public byte[] GetPixelBytes(WriteableBitmap bitmap)
{
   int[] pixels = bitmap.Pixels;
   int length = pixels.Length * 4;
   byte[] result = new byte[length]; // ARGB
   Buffer.BlockCopy(pixels, 0, result, 0, length);
   return result;
}
```

Once you have the bytes, getting colors is easy with any of the various Color APIs.

Answer (score -1):

```
Color.FromArgb(intVal)
```

Comment: to clarify, there is no FromArgb(int) method in Silverlight.. only FromArgb(byte, byte, byte, byte) - that is part of my problem